# Why is this Bash script not working?

Tags: bash, scripts

I wrote a small [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) script so that the image in the folder becomes the wallpaper:

```
for f in *.jpg
do 
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:$f
```

The error is:

```
./wall.sh: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Is my code wrong? And is there a way to set wallpapers from the Internet using a Bash script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to end it with a "done", like:

```
for f in *.jpg
do 
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:$f"
done
```

But I think the best way to do it is like this:

```
for f in /path/to/dir/*.jpg
do
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://$f"
done
```

Okay, I edited the second code. Try with this.

If you want to get random wallpapers from the Internet, you can execute this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do 
    img=http://www.wallpaperup.com/wallpapers/download/$RANDOM/1920/1080
    wget -O /tmp/1080.jpg $img
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///tmp/1080.jpg"
    sleep 60
done
```

This script will change the wallpaper every 60 seconds.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I expect the downvotes are coming for the same reason this comment pointed out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/567474/why-is-the-bash-script-not-working/567481#comment781709_567481

Comment: There is absolutely no advantage to call `ls` here: the wildcards do the right thing, but [`ls` breaks things](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Furthermore, with the command substitution inside the double quotes, the only case when this will work is if there is exactly one matching file.

Comment: The first part is right, but there are so many problems with the second. The parentheses will make it run only a single time with `f` as all matching files separated by spaces. Don't use `ls`. Better to use `$(...)` than ``` `...` ```.

Comment: Well, thanks to telling me this, I didn't know it, I removed it right now. thx.

Comment: ca =n you please explain why is there two back slashes (file:///tmp/1080.jpg)? I am new to bash scripting and a detailed answer would really help..

Comment: @Bharat That's how protocols are generally specified: `name://host/path`, so `file:///tmp/1080.jpg` has `file` as the protocol name, an empty hostname (which means localhost) and `/tmp/1080.jpg` as `/path`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Answer (score 5):

In bash you end `for` blocks with a `done`, like so:

```
for f in *.jpg
do 
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:$f"
done
```

Also, [put double quotes around `$f`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), in case some file names contain spaces.

Note that I think what you are trying to achieve could be done easier with `find`:

```
find $imageDir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:{} \;
```

Replace `$imageDir` with the path to the folder you want to search. Or, if you want to run the command in the local directory you can do it like this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:$PWD/{} \;
```

Thanks [to Gilles](https://askubuntu.com/a/567493/44179) for reminding me about `$PWD`.

Answer (score 4):

Add the last line: `done`.

Also, [put double quotes around `$f`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), in case some file names contain spaces.

Thus, the whole script becomes:

```
for f in *.jpg
do 
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:$f"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

First, basic bash syntax: a `for` loop ends with the reserved word `done`.

```
for f in *.jpg
do 
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:$f
done
```

Furthermore `$f` is a relative path — it's a file name in the current directory. But as [feyray remarked](https://askubuntu.com/a/567479) that file name would not be meaningful out of context. You need to provide an absolute path. You can do that easily with the [`PWD` variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PWD), which always contains the path to the current directory. Note that `file://` URLs require two slashes for the `://` indicator plus a slash for the root directory that starts the path, which `$PWD` includes.

```
for f in *.jpg
do 
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://$PWD/$f
done
```

That's not all. If any file name contains a space, your script won't work. To avoid this pitfall, [put double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) (always put double quotes around variable substitutions).

```
for f in *.jpg
do 
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://$PWD/$f"
done
```

Comment: Actually using the two forward slashes on `file:` isn't *strictly* needed, gsettings will accept it just fine without, although perhaps it is better form.